# Using selenium in python for capturing the links in a web

Tags: python, selenium, location-href

I'm trying to capture the links of a webpage using Selenium in Python. My initial code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import time
from tqdm import tqdm
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
driver.get('https://www.lovecrave.com/shop/')
```

Then, I identified all the products (12) in the web by using:

```
perso_flist = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@class='excerpt']")
```

Then, I want to capture the links for each product by using:

```
listOflinks = []
for i in perso_flist:
    link_1=i.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[@href[1]]")
    listOflinks.append(link_1)
print(listOflinks
```

And my output looks like:

```
print(listOflinks)  # 12 EMPTY VALUES
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

What is wrong with my code? I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: The xpath in this line is not matching anything `i.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[@href[1]]")`

Comment: Please add the html of an element matched with the xpath `"//p[@class='excerpt']"`

Comment: Thanks Jortega. How could I fix this issue in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you loop through the a tags and get the attribute href.

```
hrefs=[x.get_attribute("href") for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@class='excerpt']/following-sibling::a[1]")]
print(hrefs)
```

or xpath //li/a[@class='full-link']

Outputs

```
['https://www.lovecrave.com/products/duet-pro/',
 'https://www.lovecrave.com/products/vesper/',
 'https://www.lovecrave.com/products/wink/',
 'https://www.lovecrave.com/products/duet/',
 'https://www.lovecrave.com/products/duet-flex/',
 'https://www.lovecrave.com/products/flex/',
 'https://www.lovecrave.com/products/pocket-vibe/',
 'https://www.lovecrave.com/products/bullet/',
 'https://www.lovecrave.com/products/cuffs/',
 'https://www.lovecrave.com/shop/gift-card/',
 'https://www.lovecrave.com/shop/leather-case/',
 'https://www.lovecrave.com/shop/vesper-replacement-charger/']
```

Answer (score 1):

I am making some assumptions about this xpath `//p[@class='excerpt']` if below does not work please add an htlm example of the element.

You can get a list of link element by making this update:

```
perso_flist = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li//a[@class='full-link']")
```

Then loop through the list using `element.get_attribute()`

```
listOflinks = []
for i in perso_flist:
    link_1=i.get_attribute("href")
    listOflinks.append(link_1)
print(listOflinks)
```

Comment: Thanks, Jortega. Adding //a my output is still empty. What other xtml element may I use?

Comment: @mlosada In addition to adding //a also update your loop.  I need to know what the output of `i.get_attribute('innerHTML')` returns. I will also add this line to the answer.

Comment: My output is a short description of each product taken from the page of products and:
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None] My list of links is still empty.

Comment: as I said before, applying the updated code, I get the description of the products and my list of links remains empty.